# I need to classify a ranking of assets

Tags: r, classification, ranking

I have a table of assets ranked as below with several dates and a basket of different assets each day:

```
  asset rank       date
1     A    1 2022-11-04
2     B    2 2022-11-04
3     C    3 2022-11-04
4     D    4 2022-11-04
5     K    1 2022-11-03
6     A    2 2022-11-03
7     T    3 2022-11-03
8     M    4 2022-11-03
9     J    5 2022-11-03
```

And I need to add a colunm with short or long position: if the rank is the lowest value is short and with the highest is long.  Basically, I need to get this:

```
  asset rank       date position
1     A    1 2022-11-04 short
2     B    2 2022-11-04 -
3     C    3 2022-11-04 -
4     D    4 2022-11-04 long
5     K    1 2022-11-03 short
6     A    2 2022-11-03 -
7     T    3 2022-11-03 -
8     M    4 2022-11-03 -
9     J    5 2022-11-03 long
```

I expecting the get the short and long position of several assets per day. Each day I have a x number of asset, I ranked it and the lowest value I need to get a short position and the highest value the long position.

Comment: Please quantify "short" (and "long" aka not short). How is it that you can determine a position for assets `J` and `K` when you only have one observation each?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly. In the day 04, I have a basket of 4 assets, the asset A is the best in my classification order and D is the worst. In the day 03, I had a basket of 5 assets, asset K was the best one and J was the worst one. Each day, I have a different basket of asset and I need to classifity only the best and the worst. It does not matter if it is short or long, it can be 1 and 0, but I only need 2 assets, the best one and the worst one.

Comment: Okay, I think I misunderstood. You mean that per-day, "rank 1 is always short" and "rank last is always long", is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be a little defensive here (it may be a little overkill) in not assuming we'll always have `rank == 1`. It's not horrible ...

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(position = case_when(rank == min(rank) ~ "short", rank == max(rank) ~ "long")) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 9 x 4
#   asset  rank date       position
#   <chr> <int> <chr>      <chr>   
# 1 A         1 2022-11-04 short   
# 2 B         2 2022-11-04 NA      
# 3 C         3 2022-11-04 NA      
# 4 D         4 2022-11-04 long    
# 5 K         1 2022-11-03 short   
# 6 A         2 2022-11-03 NA      
# 7 T         3 2022-11-03 NA      
# 8 M         4 2022-11-03 NA      
# 9 J         5 2022-11-03 long
```

### base R

```r
quux$position <- c("short", "long")[
  ave(quux$rank, quux$date,
      FUN = function(z) ifelse(z == min(z), 1, ifelse(z == max(z), 2, NA)))
]
quux
#   asset rank       date position
# 1     A    1 2022-11-04    short
# 2     B    2 2022-11-04     <NA>
# 3     C    3 2022-11-04     <NA>
# 4     D    4 2022-11-04     long
# 5     K    1 2022-11-03    short
# 6     A    2 2022-11-03     <NA>
# 7     T    3 2022-11-03     <NA>
# 8     M    4 2022-11-03     <NA>
# 9     J    5 2022-11-03     long
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(quux)
quux[, position := fcase(
  rank == min(rank), "short",
  rank == max(rank), "long"), by = .(date)]
#     asset  rank       date position
#    <char> <int>     <char>   <char>
# 1:      A     1 2022-11-04    short
# 2:      B     2 2022-11-04     <NA>
# 3:      C     3 2022-11-04     <NA>
# 4:      D     4 2022-11-04     long
# 5:      K     1 2022-11-03    short
# 6:      A     2 2022-11-03     <NA>
# 7:      T     3 2022-11-03     <NA>
# 8:      M     4 2022-11-03     <NA>
# 9:      J     5 2022-11-03     long
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(asset = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "K", "A", "T", "M", "J"), rank = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), date = c("2022-11-04", "2022-11-04", "2022-11-04", "2022-11-04", "2022-11-03", "2022-11-03", "2022-11-03", "2022-11-03", "2022-11-03")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```